# laravel 4.2 https can't load asset file

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, ssl, laravel-blade

so i tried to add https/SSL from cloudflare into my laravel app by adding this line into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and it is automatically redirecting all request from http to https but i got new problem, all my asset file (css,js and images) are http and so it refuse to load and i am getting this error in console

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sm-trust.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://sm-trust.com/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

i am using blade for including all my css,js and images

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), true) }}
```

how to fix it? so it will automatically load asset with https

and also here is my complete .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure websites are not allowed to mix protocols. Everything has to be embedded from a secure server. Browsers will ignore/block HTTP resources on HTTPS pages (with varying degree of strictness).

The reason for this blocking is that insecure HTTP resources like stylesheets and scripts could still be modified by an attacker and used to spoof/hijack secure parts of the site.

If the stylesheet is served from your server, then omit protocol+host part of the URL, i.e. instead of http://example.com/style.css use /style.css as the URL, so it'll work on both HTTP and HTTPS. You can also use protocol-relative URLs.

If you have to have one full URL, then use https://… URLs only.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers), you can do something like this

```
echo link_to_asset('foo/bar.zip', $title, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);
```

The fourth parameter allows you to load a secure asset.